# Can Impala create a table with Chinese column names?

Tags: impala

I try to create a table which has Chinese column names in Impala-Shell, but It seems Impala doesn't accept such DDL.

the sql is something like this:

```
create table aa(`编号` string);
```

And Impala-shell will complain that `编号` is a invalid column name.

I also tied to use double quote or single quote, and didn't work neither.

But Spark SQL and Hive SQL accept this DDL...

So did I do something wrong, or Impala just work this way?

P.S. I am using Impala CHD 5.8.0

Comment: AFAIK Impala supports a column named `98_` but Hive does not. And `987` is invalid for both. But `_87` is valid for both. Did you try `_编号`??

Comment: the leading underscore doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
The documentation is very clear about it.

> - An identifier must start with an alphabetic character.    The    remainder can contain any combination of alphanumeric characters and underscores.    Quoting the identifier with backticks has no effect on the allowed characters in the name.
> - An identifier can contain only ASCII characters.
>
> https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_identifiers.html#identifiers

Comment: In practice, Impala is a bit more lax, and has slighly different rules for table name and column name... Go figure.